# Dev PC setup using a tool like Chef

Tags: windows, automation, installation, chef-infra

Is it possible to use a tool like Chef or Puppet to configure old development tools to install on Windows 10?

For example, we have the unfortunate problem where we have to develop and target Windows CE6.0, and require Visual Source Safe, and VB6 and VS2017 and VS2008 etc as we still have old legacy stuff.

Getting all this running is a headache.  When it breaks users spend days messing around removing registry settings, reinstalling and crossing fingers.

I was thinking, there has to be a better way.  The original installers don't always work and when you uninstall something, another tool might break.

I'm not familiar with Chef/Puppet but I am familiar with ansible on Linux and know I could get it working there.  But windows for me is a whole different ball game.  What's peoples experience here.   Could it work, and if it could work where do you find recipes/scripts for specific tools or figure them out?

Comment: What about using VMs?

Comment: I'd prefer it native.  Not VM.  Due to custom hardware etc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run chef-client on your workstation too and configure stuff. If you are not familiar with Chef, start with documentation and tutorials from their [webpage](https://www.chef.io/).